# Android: AsyncTask

Tags: android

En un AsyncTask se puede poner una condicion donde depende del dato que obtenga realize las funciones correspondientes?
Ejmplo, tengo un AsyncTask que desde un inicio le mandaba un arreglo pero ahora quiero modificar ese AsyncTask pero ya no solo lo podra utilizar la clase que mandaba el arreglo, ahora quiero que tambien lo ocupe otra clase y dependiendo de lo que se mande que realize lo que le corresponda.

Aclaro que el AsyncTask lo tengo por separado en una clase.

En una clase mando al AsyncTask un JSONObject

```
new UploadImage().execute(jsonObject);
```

De otra clase mando al AsyncTask un ArrayLIst de Bitmaps

```
new UploadImage().execute(listOfBitmaps);
```

Pero como valido en ese AsycTack lo que me mandan porque cada uno realiza cosas diferentes pero solo quiero ocupar ese AsycTask para no tener que crear otro

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Object... params) {//ejecuta nuestras tareas principales

}
```

Comment: Lo intentaste dentro de tu clase?

Comment: deja agrego codigo y explico mas a detalle

Comment: listo sioesi ya agregue codigo y un poco mas de explicacion

Answer (score 2):

No, no se puede el parametro de entrada es el que corresponde. Si tu defines que va a recibir un arreglo, debes enviar un arreglo no puede ser dinamico ese dato, para eso deberias hacer 2 clases distintas y antes de llamarlas identifica que tipo de datos tienes para saber cual llamar.

**EDIT**

Tambien (no puedo probar esto ahora) puedes recibir un `Object` y dentro de tu metodo `doInBackground` identificar la instancia con `instance of`

Comment: ok sioesi muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: @Javierfr edite mi respuesta, intenta eso